# Magento EE store permissions

Tags: admin, permissions, user-roles, ee-1.14

according to Magento http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee/user_guide/store-operations/permissions.html

> In addition, you can further restrict Admin access to only a specific site, or set of sites and their associated data. If you have multiple brands or business units with separate stores on the same Magento installation, you can provide Admin access to each of your business units but hide and protect their data from other Admin users. If an Admin user’s access is restricted to a specific set of websites and/or stores, the websites and stores for which they are not authorized will either not appear or be grayed-out as inactive. Only the sales and other data for allowed websites and stores is shown.

I cannot figure out how to restrict an admin login to a specific storeview - has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the super-admin (means you have full access to the entire site). You can Go to **system > permission > roles** create a new role then under the tab **Role resource** you can find "Roles scope" value, here is where you can defined what store view, website the role should  have access, save the role. Now is time to create a new admin with this new role. So go to **System > Permissions > Users** create a new admin user and assign the new role just created. Save and try to access with this new admin user and you are going to see only the scope access and the places you define to this user.

Let me know if this explication helps you.
Best,
Alejandro.

Comment: I don't see the store view options under role scope, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I see it now, not sure how I missed it before, thank you

Comment: @Haim was a pleasure! Feel free to add any more question, I'll glad to help you.